# Import TypeScript from JavaScript using webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, webpack

**Edit**: I simply forgot to add typescript and ts-loader dependencies to my project..

I'm trying to import a file called Test.ts from my main.js.

Test.js:

```js
export default class Test {}
```

main.js:

```js
import Test from './Test' // or `const Test = require('./Test')`
```

In my webpack.config.js I have the following:

```json
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

On compilation I get the following error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./Test in ./src/main.js
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show your project's file tree. Where is Test.ts?

Comment: @E_net4 It is right next to main.js.

Comment: `export default class Test {}`

Comment: @mumair That's what I have, sorry I initially simplified the code, I changed my post to reflect that.

Comment: @Yovar I got official `ts-loader` documentation, can you please follow this https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader confirm if it didn't work for you

Comment: @mumair I found that I forgot to include typescript and ts-loader packages.. It is strange that webpack didn't complain about a non-existing loader used in webpack.config.js.. Thank you for the help, and sorry.

Comment: you are welcome :)